# how to install mathdom in windows 8

Tags: python, windows

This is what I get for `python -v` in command prompt

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600
32 bit (In tel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or
"license" for more information.
```

When I type `python setup.py install` I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Midhun\Desktop\mathdom>python setup.py install
  File "setup.py", line 76
    """ % (REQUIRE_PACKAGES_FOR_BUILD,
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You cannot use Python 3 (3.4.3 in your case). According to https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mathdom/0.8, MathDOM is "**a set of Python 2.4 modules**".